# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: web-services, sms, bad-request

I am trying to send SMS from my web application. I am cosuming a 3rd party Webservice to Push Messages. In the development environment i can able to send SMS, When the same application hosted in production am receiving the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

> Following are the changes i did in the web.config:

```
     <system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
      </system.net>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IBulkSMS" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="500000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10500" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

> 

```
<endpoint address="SMS.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IBulkSMS"
    contract="IBulkSMS.IBulkSMS" name="IBulkSMS" >
     <identity>
     <servicePrincipalName value="host/MachineName" />
    </identity>
    </endpoint>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to fix the issue.

The proxy settings is disabled in the Production server.

> Set useDefaultWebProxy="false" if proxy is disabled. Set
>   useDefaultWebProxy="true" if proxy is enabled.

I made the following change in the binding.

```
<binding name="IBulkSMS" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="4194304" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="false">
```

It works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Set `useDefaultWebProxy="false"`  in client application